# Prove that $E$ is sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: measure-theory

Let 
$E=\{u\subset \mathbb{R} : \text{$u$ is finite or $\complement u$ is finite}\}$
Prove that $E$ is a sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}$.

I had checked the three conditions of a sigma algebra, and actually I got the proof.

But I'm confused because for example 
$\{A_i=\{i\}\}$ belong to $E$ for all $i$, but the union doesn't!
And that doesn't match the condition of closed under countable union.
What is my mistake?
I think my example is false, but why?

Comment: You made no mistake. In fact, you proved correctly that $E$ is **not** a $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by  José Carlos Santos, you proved that $E$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra.

A small modification of the definition of $E$ would make is a $\sigma$-algebra, namely, replacing the word "finite" by "at most countable".